# mongoose how to find all data from object?

Tags: database, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

Just I want to find all data that have the same ID of an object but is not working

```
   app.get("/admin/phase/:level", function(req,res){

            Level.findOne({_id: req.params.level},function(err,onelevel){
            console.log(onelevel._id)
            Semster.find({level: onelevel._id},function(err,semster){

                    Module.find({semster: semster._id } , function(err , modules){
                    console.log(semster)
                        res.render("semster",{onelevels: onelevel, semsters: semster, modules: modules})})})})});
```

Comment: What error your getting ?

Comment: when I write console.log (semester._id) the error is " undefined " because semester is Object

Comment: use `semester[0]._id`

Comment: yes it works but if i don't know  how much document... for example semester.[N]._id

Comment: Okay, Got your problem now !

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr when you use Mode.find() even if there is one document coming back is it still an array?

Comment: @Colin, Yes ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using [async and await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) on your database queries so mongoose has enough time to find the document. With that being said, I would use try-catch blocks to respond to errors in queries.

```
app.get("/admin/phase/:level",async function(req,res){
  try{
    const onelevel = await Level.findOne({_id: req.params.level});
    const semster = await Semster.find({level: onelevel._id});
    let modules = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < semster.length; i++){
      let module = await Module.find({semster: semster[i]._id });
      modules.push(...module)
    };

        res.render("semster",{
            onelevels: onelevel,
            semsters: semster,
            modules: modules})
        })
      })
    })
  catch(err){
    res.status(500).render("/uhOhPage",{
        message: err.message
    })
 });
```

Comment: it does not work because the problem with the object semster._id if i whrite semster[0]._id or semster  
it works because semster is object ,i want to find all document semster and all ref module

Comment: I redid it so that it captures all the modules but there should only be one semster in the array. if you are using find one in the call above and by its unique id.

Answer (score 0):

We solve this problem either by using the [MongoDB Aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) or using loop with [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). I like you to prefer using MongoDB as its a preferred and optimal method to do this.

**Using JavaScript :**

```
app.get("/admin/phase/:level", async function (req, res) {

    Level.findOne({ _id: req.params.level }, function (err, onelevel) {
        Semster.find({ level: onelevel._id }, function (err, semsters) {
            const modulePromise = semsters.map(semster => Module.find({ semster: semster._id }));
            var modules = await Promise.all(modulePromise);
            res.render("semster", { onelevels: onelevel, semsters: semsters, modules: modules })
        })
    })
});
```

Updated :

```
app.get("/admin/phase/:level", async function (req, res) {
    try {
        const onelevel = await Level.findOne({ _id: req.params.level });
        const semsters = await Semster.find({ level: onelevel._id });
        const modulePromise = semsters.map(semster => Module.find({ semster: semster._id }));
        var modules = await Promise.all(modulePromise);
        res.render("semster", { onelevels: onelevel, semsters: semsters, modules: modules })
    } catch (err) {
        //Your Error Handler
    }
});
```

**Using Mongo Aggregate :**

```
app.get("/admin/phase/:level", function (req, res) {
    Level.findOne({ _id: req.params.level }, function (err, onelevel) {
        Semster.aggregate([
            { $match: { level: onelevel._id } },
            { $lookup: { from: "module", localField: "_id", foreignField: "semster", as: "module" } }
        ], function (err, semsters) {
            res.render("semster", { onelevels: onelevel, semsters: semsters})
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: first erro is SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function i delete await and i get other error ReferenceError: promises is not defined and when i delete await Promise.all(promises); and i run node app it works but i think the module is null .
when i use console.log(modules)

Comment: i get this [ Query {
    _mongooseOptions: {},
    _transforms: [],
    _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map {}, _posts: Map {} },
    _executionCount: 0,
    mongooseCollection:
     NativeCollection {
       collection: [Object],
       opts: [Object],
       name: 'modules',
       collectionName: 'modules',
       conn: [Object],

Comment: I added `async` on function router check and add

Comment: use `await Promise.all(modules);`